# How to get All test Methods name?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to get All the test Methods names. How Can I do that?

Comment: Well, you can enumerate all classes in a assembly and all methods in a class using reflections and check each method if it is decorated with ```TestMethodAttribute```.

Comment: @Vadim could you please show an example. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

```
using System.Reflection;
namespace SomeUnitTests
{
  [TestClass]
  public class SomeTestClass
  {
    private static List<MethodInfo> _testMethods = new List<MethodInfo>();

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
      Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      Type type = asm.GetType(context.FullyQualifiedTestClassName);
      foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
      {
        object[] attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 1)
        {
          _testMethods.Add(method);
        }
        else
        {
          // not a test --> ignore
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**
Here is code, that stores just method's names in a list

```
private static List<string> _testMethods = new List<string>();

[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
{
  Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  Type type = asm.GetType(context.FullyQualifiedTestClassName);
  foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
  {
    object[] attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length == 1)
    {
      _testMethods.Add(method.Name);
    }
    else
    {
      // not a test --> ignore
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not really get, what do get? And what would you like to remove?

Comment: I see... well, ```MethodInfo``` is a type, and _testMethods is a list of objects of type ```MethodInfo```. Type ```MethodInfo``` describes any method. This object has property ```Name```, that contains the name of a method. Have a look on update.

Comment: Just have a look on updated code 1st line: ```private static List<string> _testMethods = new List<string>();``` there is ```List<string>``` instead of ```List<MethodInfo>```